# Does the null space of the design matrix X have an interpretation in statistics?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, linear-algebra, efficiency

I am going through the material I learned in my linear algebra classes and I am trying to view the material from a statistical perspective. This typically boils down to imagining what the theorems say interpreting $A\pmb x= \pmb b$ as a problem we would like to solve for $\pmb x$ taking as given $A$ (the design matrix) and $\pmb b$ the vector of realisations of the outcome variable. I arrived at the concept of the null space $$ \text{Def: The null space of a matrix A is the set of all solutions of the homogenous equation $A \pmb x=\pmb 0$}.$$ Does the null space have any interesting interpretation in statistics? My guess would be that is may have something to say about estimation efficiency and multicollinearity since the null space is a statement about the existence of linear dependence between your predictors.

Comment: A basic theorem--perhaps the most fundamental theorem in linear algebra--asserts the domain modulo the kernel is isomorphic, as a vector space, to the image.  The kernel thereby adds no information that isn't in the column space of the design matrix in the first place.  In particular circumstances, no doubt, elements of the kernel could have statistical interpretations: but that requires a specific context and additional mathematical structure.  Would you perhaps have an application in mind?

Comment: The application I have in mind is linear regression of y on X. But to be consistent with the above formulation I should say regressing b on A, I suppose. Would this application invite any further 'insights' of the null space (is the kernel synonymous with null space?).